# Java 8 stream computation on whole list

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

I see [Let’s Get Lazy: Explore the Real Power of Streams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=873E68cylNo) video on youtube (venkat subramaniam). (minute 26-30 approx.)

In the example, a for loop:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
int result = 0;
for(int e: values){
  if(e > 3 && e % 2 == 0){
    result = e * 2;
    break;
  }
}
```

having 8 "unit operations"

according to his example :

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

        System.out.println(
                numbers.stream()
                        .filter(e -> e > 3)
                        .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
                        .map(e -> e * 2)
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElse(0)
        );


    }
}
```

this code looks like it has 21 "unit operations".

And then he recommends to use this code:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

        System.out.println(
                numbers.stream()
                        .filter(MainClass::isGT3)
                        .filter(MainClass::isEven)
                        .map(MainClass::doubleIt)
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElse(0)
        );


    }

    private static int doubleIt(Integer e) {
        return e * 2;
    }

    private static boolean isEven(Integer e) {
        return e % 2 == 0;
    }

    private static boolean isGT3(Integer e) {
        return e > 3;
    }
}
```

Really I want to understand, how can this be proved that has 8 unit operations instead of 21 unit operations?

Comment: An external YouTube video is not a very good basis for a question on this forum.  Your question should ideally include, as _text_, all information needed for someone to give you an answer.

Comment: @mah454 The computation total in the video is related to the code as (stream 10+filter 7+ filter 4) before finding the first element matching the condition. But with the terminal operation as in place, you can evaluate the computations to the exact value which would be 8 with the use of AtomicInteger count increased by 1 for every operation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are totally right. I edited the question extracting the parts and the code needed to be properly asked. Thanks for notice that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No no no, you misunderstood the idea. The idea is the lazy evaluation on streams. And both takes "8 computations" (using his words), he tried to say that it looked like it would take 21.

This

```
  numbers.stream()
                  .filter(MainClass::isGT3)
                  .filter(MainClass::isEven)
                  .map(MainClass::doubleIt)
                  .findFirst()
                  .orElse(0)
```

And

```
numbers.stream()
                .filter(e -> e > 3)
                .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
                .map(e -> e * 2)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(0)
```

Are **Exactly the same**. The only difference is create a function to be more readable and that's all. 
 The imperative code:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
int result = 0;
for(int e: values){
  if(e > 3 && e % 2 == 0){
    result = e * 2;
    break;
  }
}
```

and the code in the streams, computes exact the same, because they are called on demand, it means it doesn't filter all `> 3` and the filter all `% 2 == 0`, no, it combines that operations, and then apply it when a terminal function is called (like `findFirst()`)

As the video shows, if you put some prints between the functions, it will show the 8 operations:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

        System.out.println(processStream(numbers)); 
        System.out.println(getNumber(numbers));
        System.out.println(getNumberEfficient(numbers));
    }

    static Stream<Integer> processStream(List<Integer> numbers){
        return numbers.stream()
                .filter(e -> {
                    System.out.println("GT3: " + e);
                    return e > 3;
                })
                .filter(e -> {
                    System.out.println("is Even: " + e);
                    return e % 2 == 0;
                })
                .map(e -> {
                    System.out.println("times 2: " + e);
                    return e * 2;
                } );
    }

    static int getNumberEfficient(List<Integer> numbers){
        return numbers.stream()
                .filter(e -> {
                    System.out.println("GT3 and even: " + e);
                    return e > 3 && e % 2 == 0;
                })
                .map(e -> {
                    System.out.println("times 2: " + e);
                    return e * 2;
                } )
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(0);
    }

    static int getNumber(List<Integer> numbers){
        return numbers.stream()
                .filter(e -> {
                    System.out.println("GT3: " + e);
                    return e > 3;
                })
                .filter(e -> {
                    System.out.println("is Even: " + e);
                    return e % 2 == 0;
                })
                .map(e -> {
                    System.out.println("times 2: " + e);
                    return e * 2;
                } )
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(0);
    }
}
```

it will return:

> This is the pipeline, nothing was executed, because is laze

```
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@7ba4f24f
```

> Thees are the 8 operations:

```
GT3: 1
GT3: 2
GT3: 3
GT3: 5
is Even: 5
GT3: 4
is Even: 4
times 2: 4
8
```

> And this is a little optimization, instead of doing two filters, you can do only one, and reduce from 8 to 6:

```
GT3 and even: 1
GT3 and even: 2
GT3 and even: 3
GT3 and even: 5
GT3 and even: 4
times 2: 4
8
```